# Does IBM Cloud Availability Monitoring work when IBM Cloud is down?

Tags: ibm-cloud, high-availability, availability-monitoring

When IBM Cloud is down, does it also affect the [Availability Monitoring](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/availability-monitoring) service? I understand tests are run from locations around the world and it should not really fail when IBM Cloud is down.

Also any information on high availability and failover support for IBM Cloud Availability Monitoring is appreciated.

Comment: This is aproduct and not a programming question. I would recommend to leave feedback in the docs if it is missing or to contact support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main components of the [Availability Monitoring](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/availability-monitoring) service are hosted outside of IBM Cloud.  The UI component is hosted within IBM Cloud, but is part of the global console so as long as at least one IBM Cloud data center is up, it will continue to operate.  The [Alert Notification](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/alert-notification) functionality is provided by its sister service which is hosted within IBM Cloud.  If the Availability Monitoring service cannot forward on the alerts to the Alert Notification service, then that part of the service will not function.

The net is: it depends on where the failure in IBM Cloud is.

The service itself has HA but only within each data center, there is no HA across data centers.